# Can I manipulate functions/codes inside UnityEngine for Unity5?

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to change some fundamental codes inside UnityEngine?

For example, I want to know if I can change how acceleration behaves in reaction to the force the object is applied with

```
-> changing from F = m*a to F = m*a^2.
```

I tried doing this way:

```
void Update () {
    if (enableKinematic == true) {
        accelerationVector = forceVector / mass;
        velocityVector += accelerationVector * Time.deltaTime;
        positionVector += velocityVector * Time.deltaTime;
        // Debug.Log ("a:" + accelerationVector + " v:" + velocityVector + " d:" + positionVector);

        // Apply position
        transform.position += positionVector;
    }
}
```

But I realized that collision detection gets pretty complicated this way.

Comment: Rigidbody is a sealed class since the whole functioning relies on the fact that those methods return what they are expected to. In your case, I guess you would have to affect the velocity of the rigidbody passing the result of your own calculation.

Comment: +1 to @fafase 's comment. That said, you can always use Unity's source code (ex: https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui ) to create your own components.